# Does the DLC separate the player-base?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have played ME3 coop for the past week.  Sat->Friday had no problem getting into public games.

On Friday, I noticed there are 3 free multiplayer DLC packs.  I installed them.  Since installation, I have only seen one or two other players, no full public games.

Is the player-base fragmented by DLC installation?  Do I need to uninstall the DLC to return to rejoin the majority of public games?  If so - how do I do that?

(playing on PC)

Answer (score 1):

Players that have different combinations of multiplayer DLC packs, cannot join the same game session.  Since these packs are free, the majority of players have all of the free DLC packs.  In addition, many players are playing with none of the DLC packs.

If you have some but not all of the packs, you are unlikely to find a game.  Solve this by either downloading the remaining multiplayer DLC packs, or by unregistering the ones you have downloaded.

[This article](http://www.reddit.com/r/MECoOp/comments/19b8wm/mecoop_college_tips_and_tricks_507_uninstalling/) tells how to unregister DLC.  Go to the DLC folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Mass Effect 3\BIOGame\DLC` and rename these folders.

```
\DLC_CON_MP1 = Resurgence
\DLC_CON_MP2 = Rebellion
\DLC_CON_MP3 = Earth
\DLC_CON_MP4 = Retaliation
\DLC_CON_MP5 = Reckoning
```